# Write a function which returns the sum of the values for each parameter it receives

Tags: javascript, arguments

I want the result to be the sum of every number, but instead, it only sums the first number with the rest. For example if the parameter were : 1,2,3,4,5
it should come out with 15 but instead, it became 3456. Where did i go wrong?
Thank u guys, i m new to this and thing were really complicated :((

```
   function func1(sum) {
     var result = '';
     var i;
   for (i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     result += arguments[i] + sum;
    }
   return result;
    }
```

Comment: You should initialize `result` to 0, not an empty string.

Comment: also you should remove the `sum` parameter. `arguments` is a javascript magic property that is always available inside a function, and it lists all arguments as an array. Since you want to use an x-amount of parameters, you should use that one instead of a fixed parameter like `sum`. Furthermore, `i` should start with 0 because arrays (in 'every' programming language) start at index 0 and not at index 1.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start with `result` being a number, not a string: `var result = 0`.
2. If you're iterating through `arguments`, you may as well skip the named first argument altogether.
3. Start iterating from 0, not 1.

```js
   function func1() {
     var result = 0;
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
       result += arguments[i];
     }

     return result;
    }

console.log(func1(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
function sum(value) {
let result = 0;

for(let i =0; i < value.length; i++) {
  
result +=value[i];
}
return result
}

let arry = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(sum(arry)) //15
```